# Animated timeline with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create some time line effect. It will have couple of points for each time with designated picture inside a circle.

I want them to be clickable. When I click, I want another picture(plane) to move from its current location to where it is clicked within 1 second and shrink and disappear. Something similar to following GIF.

I have found couple of examples but I couldn't put them together to achieve what I want. I really searched a lot but couldn't solve it on my own. I am an iOS developer and no background on web development.

I will appreciate if you can help me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give a relative position to the timeline. Then you can get the position of a clicked circle, and assign it to the movable one. Add CSS transitions to have a better visual result.

Example using jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".point", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $abs = $(".is-absolute");

    $abs.css("top", $this.position().top);
    $abs.css("left", $this.position().left);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dsr4esn3/

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is very close to what I want to achieve but there some problems. I want to move a picture along y axis. When clicked picture appears, moves, shrinks, disappears. Also I want beginning and end circles without tail. Lastly, I will really appreciate if you can put time and location text on left and right. I am sorry for bugging but I am really clueless.